# How can I start an interactive program(like gdb) from python?

Tags: python, gdb

I am going to start up gdb from python.

For example:

```
prog.shell.py:
    #do lots of things
    #
    #
    p.subprocess.Popen("gdb --args myprog", shell=True, stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=sys.stdout)
```

But the gdb is not invoked as I expected, the interaction with gdb is broken. I have also tried os.system(), but it still doesnt work.  What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant

```
p = subprocess.Popen(...)
```

You probably need to wait for p to finish:

```
p.wait()
```